# What is this property in model theory called?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Take three L-structures: $\cal{M}_0 \subset\cal{M}_1 \subset\cal{M}_2$. If $\cal{M}_0 \prec \cal{M}_2$ and $\cal{M}_1 \prec \cal{M}_2$, then we have $\cal{M}_0 \prec \cal{M}_1$.

Does this property have a name?

Comment: Sounds like transitivity of the $\prec$ symbol, although I don't know enough model theory to understand what the $\prec$ symbol is.

Comment: @user400188 Not quite! Note the conclusion is $M_0 \prec M_1$, not $M_0\prec M_2$. The symbol $\prec$ means "elementary substructure".

Comment: @user400188 No, transitivity would be "$\mathcal{M}_0\prec \mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_1\prec\mathcal{M}_2$ implies $\mathcal{M}_0\prec\mathcal{M}_2$" - this is weirder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the axioms of [abstract elementary classes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_elementary_class), and in that context it is called "coherence".