# Does every saturated infinite model $A$ have a proper elementary extension B, such that $\lvert A\rvert =\lvert B\rvert$

Tags: logic, model-theory

The Upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem can give us an elementary extension of the same cardinality, but I am not sure how to prove that this is a proper elementary extension.

Comment: Use the *proof* of Löwenheim-Skolem rather than just its statement.

Comment: Are you assuming that the language $L$ is countable, or at least that $|A|\geq |L|$?

Comment: oh yes, should have mentioned that, but L is countable @AlexKruckman

Comment: This should be true even without the assumption of saturation (assuming the language is countable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with saturation.

Given an infinite structure $A$ in a language of cardinality $\le\vert A\vert$, let $\hat{A}$ be **any** proper elementary extension of $A$ (which exists by compactness). Now pick $a\in \hat{A}\setminus A$, and apply downward Lowenheim-Skolem to $\hat{A}$ to get an elementary substructure $A\cup\{a\}\subseteq B\preccurlyeq \hat{A}$ with $\vert B\vert=\vert A\cup\{a\}\vert$ (note that $\vert A\cup\{a\}\vert=\vert A\vert$).

Since $a\in B$ we have $A\subsetneq B$, and by [coherence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907550/what-is-this-property-in-model-theory-called) we have $A\preccurlyeq B$. So we're done.

Comment: That is really clear, thank you!

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that some sources (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem)) tend to quote the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem in an (at first sight) weaker form that doesn't directly support the argument here. The full theorem does allow you not only to choose the _cardinality_ of the elementary substructure you get, but also to select an arbitrary set of concrete _elements_ of the outer model that will all be in the subsubstructure.

Comment: @Troposphere That's an inessential difference though since the weaker version gives the stronger version (just add constants naming the elements you want).

Comment: Right. Just mentioned it because it could make the argument in the answer difficult to follow if one isn't aware of the extension.